Use Prism.Unity as DI for ASP.NET Core
I am working on a shared code base between a client and an ASP.NET Core application.
My problem is that ASP.NET Core uses Microsoft.DI and the client uses Prism.Unity, which leads to a log of code duplication.
Because of this I am currently looking for a solution to use Prism.Unity instead of Microsoft DI, in the backend. Is there any solution available, or any reason to not do it?
Prism with ASP.NET which doesn't really helped me. I want to use only Prism.Unity not replacing the whole backend.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/343887/replace-asp-net-cores-di-container-with-external-container - Sounds good, but it's a little bit old
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext/ - Sounds good, but it's a little bit old

First, you're using the Unity Container through the Prism.Unity adapter. Both are very old, over-engineered and simply not used by NuGet packages. And dual-licensed, which probably means you have to pay to use that old software. All NuGet packages use the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions`, so they don't really care about the DI implementation. Perhaps the best option would be to create a Prism adapter for .NET's DI, not the other way around

The article you found is correct even if old - you can create an adapter that replaces .NET's DI implementation with another one. Given Unity's age though, there doesn't seem to be an adapter for it.  The list of alternative adapters includes DryLoc. Prism includes an adapter for DryLoc as well
